# Algolia Highlight function for search results doesn't work

Tags: javascript, node.js, algolia

I have simple test aplication in pure html and javascript with CDN.
My test code just copied from [source example](https://www.algolia.com/doc/ui-libraries/autocomplete/core-concepts/templates/) on angolia site. It looks like this:

```
autocomplete({
  container: `#autocomplete`,
  placeholder: "Search",
  getSources() {
    return [
      {
        // ...
        templates: {
          item({ item, components, html }) {
            return html`<div>
              <img src="${item.image}" alt="${item.name}" />
              <div>
                ${components.Highlight({ hit: item, attribute: 'name' })}
              </div>
            </div>`;
          },
        },
      },
    ];
  },
});
```

The seatch is working fine but

> components.Highlight

function is not workin. No any error just it doesn't highlight matched search results...
P.S I do not use algolia search engine. Just autocomplete functionality.